# Error when generate signed apk android studio 3.0

Tags: android

On Gerate signed apk the error stoped the generate:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: Same here. I had to add `lintOptions { checkReleaseBuilds false }` to my release build `buildType` after spending +24h trying to solve this.